# How to allow resending form when Sequelize validation error is thrown in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a following SignUp controller for registering users to my system. I've got a problem with `form.$valid` property, which is frozen to false, when the validation error from Sequelize is thrown...What should I add/change in my controller? I think, it should erase false $valid value for specific input on ng-change event maybe? But I don't know, how to achieve this...

```
class SignupController {
  //start-non-standard
  user = {};
  errors = {};
  submitted = false;
  //end-non-standard

  constructor(Auth, $state) {
    this.Auth = Auth;
    this.$state = $state;
  }

  register(form) {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(this.errors);
    if (form.$valid) {
      console.log("clikc");
      this.Auth.createUser({
        nickname: this.user.nickname,
        email: this.user.email,
        password: this.user.password
      })
      .then(() => {
        // Account created, redirect to home
        this.$state.go('main');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        err = err.data;
        this.errors = {};

        // Update validity of form fields that match the sequelize errors
        if (err.name) {
          angular.forEach(err.fields, function(value, key) {
            form[key].$setValidity('sequelize', false);
            this.errors[key] = err.message;
          }, this);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

angular.module('batnApp')
  .controller('SignupController', SignupController);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out with ng-change function, which has got a following functionality:

```
resetValidation(form, field) {
  if(this.submitted && !form.$valid) { //validation is on server side
    form[field].$setValidity('sequelize', true);
  }
}
```